# How to declare a function to be equal to another function in as3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

If I wanted to create a function called printMe, what's the proper syntax so that it prints what the function information prints?

```
var named:String="me";
var age:int=100;



function information():void{
    trace(named, age);
}

information();
```

I tried a few things like

```
printMe=information;
printMe();
```

Here are the errors I'm getting

Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 8   1120: Access of undefined property printMe.

Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 9   1180: Call to a possibly undefined method printMe.

Comment: It's helpful if you post the errors you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
var printMe:Function = information;
printMe();
```